# Android SQLite DatabaseObjectNotClosedException

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

In a PoC Android app I'm building, I'm getting an `android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException` when garbage collector is being called on the app on close. This is happening even when I'm invoking the close method on both the `SQLiteDatabase` as well as the `SQLiteOpenHelper` objects that I'm using.

I'm accessing the DB using a DAO(called from an `AsyncTask.doInBackground` of an `Activity`) that holds the code for opening the DB in the constructor, and this constructor is invoked from the `onCreate()` method of an activity.

```
//Code in my DAO class
public MyDataSource(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new MyOpenHelper(context);
    dbHelper.createDatabase();
}

//Calling Activity
MyDataSource myDs;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.create);

    myDs= new MyDataSource (MyActivity.this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    investmentDs.close();
    if(ConstantValues.DebugModeManager.DEBUG_CREATE || ConstantValues.DebugModeManager.DEBUG_MODE) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Create screen paused...");
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

I've also got a method for closing the `SQLiteDatabase` as well as the `SQLiteOpenHelper`objects, which is invoked from the `onPause()` method of the same activity. The database read/write is performed in the `doInBackground` method of an AsyncTask.

I've overriden the `close()` method for the `SQLiteOpenHelper` as follows:

```
@Override
public synchronized void close() {
        if(database != null)
            database.close();
        super.close(); 
}
```

I'm calling this from a `close()` method in my DAO class.

Please let me know if further clarification is required.
Thanks,
Debojit

**EDIT 1:**
This is the code for fetching from db.

```
    cursor = db.query("EMPLOYEES", null, whereClause, null, null, null, "EMPLOYEE_ID");
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    List<MyBean> beans = new ArrayList<MyBean>();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        beans.add(cursorToObject(cursor)); //this fetches data from the cursor's current row            
        cursor.moveToNext(); // and inserts into a POJO of type MyBean

    }
    cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor object is not closed.
Whenever you are done with Cursor object call **cursor.close();**

Comment: I'm closing the cursor _immediately_ after I fetch data and load it into an `ArrayList`.